# Oracle - Select rows Group By based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I want to fetch duplicate rows for a particular date & time, group by both `bname` and `txn_date` **AND** `txn_date` up to Hours and Minutes (Seconds do not need to match)

For Example, I fetch the rows below for `txn_date = 2020/07/28`, `txn_type = OPD`, `payment_mode = CREDIT` and `inv_num` begins with `AGL`

Out of these, I want only rows with IDs from 1 - 4

```
ID |         txn_date       |   bname        
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | 2020/07/28 10:21:58 PM |  MRS R A W B VERNON
 2 | 2020/07/28 10:21:56 PM |  MRS R A W B VERNON
 3 | 2020/07/28 09:51:58 AM |  MRS TRIDENTZ
 4 | 2020/07/28 09:51:58 AM |  MRS TRIDENTZ
 5 | 2020/07/28 09:49:51 AM |  MRS TRIDENTZ
 6 | 2020/07/28 08:33:14 AM |  MRS TRIDENTZ
 7 | 2020/07/28 08:25:06 AM |  MRS S F D SHERILA
 8 | 2020/07/28 08:11:35 AM |  MRS S F D SHERILA
```

I use this query below.

```
select to_char(l.txn_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH12:MI:SS AM') "DATE",l.bname
from linv l where (bname) IN (select bname from linv
where txn_date like '28-JUL-20%'
group by bname, txn_date
having count(*) > 1) and l.txn_type = 'OPD' and payment_mode = 'CREDIT' 
and inv_num like 'AGL%' 
and txn_date like '28-JUL-20%'
order by l.txn_date desc, l.bname
```

But this does not give me the desired output as some of the required rows are not fetching.

I tried to change group by to `to_char(txn_date, 'HH24')` but that did not work too.

I think the `group_by txn_date` has the issue but couldn't get it fixed. Can some one please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I made some edits and specified the results I want

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to group based on datetime up-to the minute, you can use TRUNC function to get rid of seconds & milliseconds.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151

Use this in your group by instead

```
group by bname, to_char(TRUNC(txn_date, 'MI'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a concern, suppose there are 3 rows with `bname` as `X` and `txn_date` as `date1-time1`. Another row with `bname` as `X` and `txn_date` as `date1-time2`. Is it possible for all 4 rows to fetch? I am experiencing that

Comment: if `time1` and `time2` are same up-to (excluding) seconds, then yes. That's the purpose of  `TRUNC(.., 'MI))` to truncate all details (seconds, milliseconds) after the minute.

Answer (score 1):

Does `exists` do what you want?

```
select l.*
from linv l
where exists (select 1
              from linv l2
              where trunc(l2.txn_date) = trunc(l.txn_date) and
                    l2.bname = l.bname
             );
```

You can add additional filters as well.  Your query suggests:

```
with l as (
      select l.*
      from linv l
      where l.txn_type = 'OPD' and
            l.payment_mode = 'CREDIT' and
            l.inv_num like 'AGL%' 
            l.txn_date >= date '2020-07-28' and
            l.txn_date < date '2020-07-29' 
           )
select l.*
from l l
where exists (select 1
              from l l2
              where trunc(l2.txn_date) = trunc(l.txn_date) and
                    l2.bname = l.bname
             );
```

Or using window functions:

```
with l as (
      select l.*
      from linv l
      where l.txn_type = 'OPD' and
            l.payment_mode = 'CREDIT' and
            l.inv_num like 'AGL%' 
            l.txn_date >= date '2020-07-28' and
            l.txn_date < date '2020-07-29' 
     )
select l.*
from (select l.*, count(*) over (partition by trunc(txn_date), bname) as cnt
      from l
     )l
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I want to give `exists` a try and used the 2nd example but it fetches all rows for `where` clauses